# Unable to encrypt unencrypted RDS DB through snapshot-copy

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I am trying to encrypt an unencrypted RDS Aurora DB. Running *MySQL* on a *db.t2.small* instance.

According to the docs, it is possible to carry this out by creating a snapshot of the unencrypted DB and then creating an encrypted copy of this snapshot.

[This](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CopySnapshot.html#USER_CopySnapshot.Encryption) is the method I was trying to follow

So I create a snapshot of the main db, encryption is not possible as expected. But the option to encrypt is grayed out even when trying to copy the snapshot. I also tried encrypting a snapshot of a snapshot. Any idea if this feature has been deprecated? Is there anything else I may be missing?

Comment: Do you have the necessary KMS permissions?  I'd speculate that the console may be trying to check that in the background and is graying-out the option due to lack of access to KMS.

Comment: It is most likely that selected instance type  does not support encryption.
Please check Availability of Amazon RDS Encrypted Instances at  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.Encryption.html

Comment: @michael-sqlbot Yes I believe I do have the permissions. My role has an AdminAccess policy.

Comment: @aress-support I’m using the t2.small which definitely has support. I’ve also tried across a variety of instance types.

Comment: Can you share screenshots? Have you tried doing the same over CLI using the copy-db-snapshot API ?

Answer (score 8):

Considering you're using Aurora, are you sure that what you have is a DB **instance** snapshot and not a DB **cluster** snapshot?

In the console, copying a cluster snapshot looks very similar to copying an instance snapshot, but they are in fact different things. When you try to copy an Aurora DB cluster snapshot, encryption is greyed out without any explanation, exactly as you described. The answer can in fact be found in the documentation, though it's buried farther than it should be:

["For Amazon Aurora DB cluster snapshots, you can't encrypt an unencrypted DB cluster snapshot when you copy the snapshot."](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_CopySnapshot.html#USER_CopySnapshot.Encryption)

The way to go for Aurora clusters apparently is to directly restore your unencrypted snapshot to a (new) encrypted cluster; that is, you can skip the copying step. This too is information you have to dig deep in the AWS documentation to find:

["[Y]ou can restore an unencrypted Aurora DB cluster snapshot to an encrypted Aurora DB cluster. To do this, specify a KMS encryption key when you restore from the unencrypted DB cluster snapshot."](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Overview.Encryption.html#Overview.Encryption.Limitations)

Comment: You are correct, the way for Aurora is to select encrypted in the new DB from an unencrypted snapshot, but with one major floor: encrypted is still ignored in CloudFormation when specifying a snapshot, even if you are using Aurora. Seems broken in IaC to me.

Comment: Yes, came across the same problem. In CloudFormation a lot of the details (master user credentials, encryption etc) are forcibly inherited from the snapshot. If you try to override them in CloudFormation, they are ignored.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbcluster.html#cfn-rds-dbcluster-storageencrypted

Comment: According to [the CloudFormation docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbcluster.html#cfn-rds-dbcluster-storageencrypted), if you specify `KmsKeyID`, it will encrypt on restore:

> If you specify the SnapshotIdentifier and the specified snapshot isn't encrypted, you can use this property to specify that the restored DB cluster is encrypted. Specify the KmsKeyId property for the KMS key to use for encryption. If you don't want the restored DB cluster to be encrypted, then don't set this property or set it to false.